# Time series representing with other time series in R

Tags: r, optimization, matching

Y | X1 | X2 | X3 | X4 | X5

and there are 10 rows. each column represents a time series data. What I want to do is, I want to combine all X columns with some weights to represent column Y. So, in this case, I just want an 5 output that represents the weight from X1 to X5.

Is it possible to make this calculation in R? what should be the initial step that I should take?

After finding this I will try to add some constraints like choosing maximum 3 different series. I am trying to use optim function but I could not find a way.

Any help is appreciated.

thanks

Comment: What did you tried so far? Please read [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question.

Comment: hi jogo, I couldnot progress that much so i didnot share what i did so far.

Comment: Have you already done a linear model `lm(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 +X5, data=yourDataframe)` or `lm(Y ~ 0 + X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 +X5, data=yourDataframe)` ?

Comment: yes i did. But I wanted to go with optim since I want to be flexible when adding new constraint like number of X to use..

Comment: I just realized that I can try fused lasso to penalize #x, i will have a look into it. still that would be nice to find a solution with optim